# Tooltip Highcharts in hybrid application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

i have created hybrid application, The default settings is tooltip displayed when we do hover in the charts.. But, is no hover in the mobile device. How to display the tooltip in the hybrid application charts ??

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                dataLabels: {

                        format : '{point.percentage:.2f}%',
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
            }
        },
        series: [{"name":"Noc Siklus 5","data":[0]},{"name":"Noc Siklus 4","data":[4503]},{"name":"Noc Siklus 3","data":[44114]},{"name":"Noc Siklus 2","data":[208034]},{"name":"Noc Siklus 1","data":[483951]}]
    });
});
```

I have created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RobbyWH/zr03ku76/) for this problem

I want the tooltip display all data with the touch function, can i do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: For me it works fine - tap on bar to see tooltip. Any specific browser/OS ?

Comment: OS Android 4.4.2, sometime we must touch twice to displayed the tooltip, i created the stack bar, and difficult to show the tooltip from one bar to another bar

Comment: And you can reproduce that issue in the above demo? I'm using 4.3, so maybe there is an issue?

Comment: The issue only occured in the device, when we run the hybrid application. I can't reproduce the issue in the browser

Comment: Maybe you are using some library which conflicts with Highcharts? Like [this one](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2452) ?

Comment: I using ionic for the UI framework, maybe angular cause this problem

Comment: Something prevents tap/click events on the chart, that's what I think. Probably without fully recreated demo we won't be able to debug/fix/suggest a workaround.

Comment: Can you bind click/tap event and check this? If tap/click is fired every time when action is made on the chart? If yes, then try in that event handler to call: `chart.pointer.runPointActions(event);`.

Comment: When i give events click on the series, it's just run well. Can i trigger that hover function on my hybrid application?

Comment: It's strange. You add click event in Highcharts object? If so, does `series.point.events.click` works fine too? If yes, then use: `series.point.events.click: function() { this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh([this]); }` Or for series: `series.events.click: function(event) { this.chart.pointer.runPointActions(event); }`.

Comment: I have following your suggestion, but the problem is still occured.

I think the tooltip can't displayed because the stack is not selected all, like on the hover method, but if the stack is selected all, the tooltip can displayed

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip can't displayed because the stack is not selected all, like on the hover method, but if the stack is selected all, the tooltip can displayed.

I just added this code below :

```
      series: {
                    events: {
                        mouseOver: function() {
                             this.series.setState('hover');

                        },
                        mouseOut: function(){
                             this.series.setState('');
                        }
                    }
            }
```